# Why my Redis Docker container shows "(empty array)" for KEYS * while I'm absolutely sure it has cached data and it works OK

Tags: laravel, docker, redis

This is chunk of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: foo_redis
    volumes:
      - ./docker/volumes/redis:/data
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - local_network
```

I can guarantee that data persists between `ups` and `downs` because I've defined `volumes`.

I can prove that data is being stored physically because I see `dump.rdb` within `./docker/volumes/redis` on my host machine.

- When I enable debugbar I can see that route where I cache stuff has no queries.
- When I clear Laravel's cache and refresh page I see number of DB queries, second refresh - no queries. Clearly it works with no issues.

Then from my host machine I do:

`docker exec -it foo_redis redis-cli`

I get a prompt:

`127.0.0.1:6379>`

I type `KEYS *` and I get:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
(empty array)
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Why? What am I doing wrong? Redis seems to works fine. My Laravel app has `predis` and caching works with no issues.

edit:

My `.env` looks like:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

edit 2:

When I manually put something into redis, it shows only that thing.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set hello world
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> get hello
"world"
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
1) "hello"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but are you sure you're using the redis driver (so also used config:clear to clear cache)?

Comment: Hi, I've added my redis config in `.env`. I use `CACHE_DRIVER=redis`.

Comment: Yes but your application does not have to honor your env file if you cached the config before changing it.

Comment: can we see how you utilize the cache in laravel code?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: No, it's still a mystery for me…

Answer (score 2):

The old answer, but maybe will be useful for someone,
**check the using Redis database number.**

If your data contains in the Redis database with a number different from 0 (default number), first set the DB number in CLI mode, using the command **SELECT <db number>**

Example: https://redis.io/docs/manual/cli/#interactive-mode